# Deleting / adding an attribute leads to deleting all <options> in <select>

Tags: html, jquery

I try to remove / add the required attribute when I click on the checkbox. I have a problem with this script below:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#billing_as_shipping", function() {
  if ($("#billing_as_shipping").is(":checked")) {
    $("#wrap-shipping-adress .addRequired").each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).prop('required', false));
    });
  } else {
    $("#wrap-shipping-adress .addRequired").each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).prop('required', true));
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="billing_as_shipping" name="billing_as_shipping">

<div id="wrap-shipping-adress">
  <select id="state" name="state" class="form-select addRequired" required>
    <option value="">Choose country</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="2">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="85">Algeria</option>
    <option value="94">Argentina</option>
    <option value="68">Armenia</option>
    <option value="5">Australia</option>
    <option value="33">Austria</option>
    <option value="56">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="45">Belarus</option>
    <option value="6">Belgium</option>
    <option value="91">Bolivia</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When I run the script it remove/ add atribute "required", but in case element `<select>` it delete all `<options>`. I tried to use it in each function :not, but it didn't work and all `<options>` disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

With `.html()`, you are replacing whole html inside select tag, so `.html()` is not required. You can handle solution without `.each()` also. Better solution is:

```
$(document).on("click","#billing_as_shipping", function(){
    if($("#billing_as_shipping").is(":checked")){
        $("#wrap-shipping-adress .addRequired").prop('required',false);
    }else{
        $("#wrap-shipping-adress .addRequired").prop('required',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `.html()` just write:

`$(this).prop('required',true))`